# cannot import name 'LoggingConfigurable'

Tags: python-3.x, conda, spyder

Spyder does not load up for me.  Splash screen appears, but then crashes out.

Things I have tried:

- spyder --reset
- conda update spyder
- conda update jupyter_core

Anything else to try?

```
(arcgispro-py3) C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3>spyder
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 3285, in main
    mainwindow = run_spyder(app, options, args)
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 3140, in run_spyder
    main.setup()
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 914, in setup
    from spyder.plugins.ipythonconsole import IPythonConsole
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\ipythonconsole.py", line 25, in <module>
    from jupyter_client.connect import find_connection_file
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .connect import *
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 25, in <module>
    from traitlets.config import LoggingConfigurable
ImportError: cannot import name 'LoggingConfigurable'
[8316:14276:0605/235021.661:ERROR:broker_win.cc(59)] Error reading broker pipe: The pipe has been ended. (0x6D)
```